# What is the best way to pass an instance method as an argument in Swift?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have an array of objects that implement some protocol FooObserver, which includes

```
protocol FooObserver{
    func didDoIt(description: String)
    func didNotDoIt(description: String)
}

class Item: FooObserver{
    func didDoIt(description: String){
        print(description)
    }
    func didNotDoIt(description: String){
        print("uh oh")
    }
}

let myArray = [Item(), Item(), Item(), Item()]

func callInstanceMethodForAllItems(method: (String) -> Void){
     // this is what I need help with
}

// or maybe I have to do it with selectors but I'm wondering if thats the best way 
// since maybe I'd rather not use the @objc flag for my instance methods 
func callInstanceMethodForAllItems(selector: Selector, arg: String){
    for o in myArray{
        o.perform(selector, with: arg) 
    }
}

// not really sure what this part would look like, maybe...
callInstanceMethodForAllItems(selector: #selector(Item().didDoit), arg: "we did it")
```

if I want to tell each object to call either `didDoIt` or `didNotDoIt` I can of course iterate over all of them and tell each one without much trouble.  But I would like to know if I can by more DRY and instead write a function that takes some identifier for the instance method and then iterates over all the objects and calls the prescribed method.  I think you can probably do this with selectors, but not exactly sure how and interested if there are other ways also.

Note that I am asking specifically about a functional treatment of references to instance methods - not for how to deal with one-to-many delegate relationships or pub-sub machinery included in swift, which one might think by looking at my example.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what is it that it gives you as opposed to something like `myArray.forEach { item in item.didDoit() }`. So can you elaborate the actual problem you are trying to solve by going that route?

Comment: Yea I guess this is the way to make it a one-liner.  I just got curious because it was clear to me how to pass around functions as arguments but not really clear how to do the same thing with instance methods in swift.  But this may be difficult for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I may be incredibly wrong in my description, but from what I understand this is the solution.

In swift, you can turn any function into a closure if you use it as a function.

```
func a() { print("ha") }
let b = a
b()//it will print 'ha'
```

You can also get an instance method as a closure if you call the method function from its type and pass the instance as an argument.

```
class Foo {
    func a() { print("haha") }
}
let foo = Foo()
let methodA = Foo.a(foo)
methodA()//prints 'haha'
```

Thus, if you do something like this,

```
class Foo {
    func a(string: String) { print(string) }
}
let x = Foo.a
```

the type of `x` will be `(Foo)->(String)->()`. It is the method to return a closure for the function `a` given an instance of `Foo`.

### Implementation

This is the function to call a specific instance method for every single element on a collection.

```
extension Collection {
    func callAll<T>(function: (Element) -> (T) -> (), with input: T){
        for element in self {
            function(element)(input)
        }
    }
}

//demonstration:
let myArray = [Item(), Item(), Item(), Item()]
myArray.callAll(function: Item.didDoIt, with: "hello")//prints 'hello' four times.
```

Note: Although this is possible, please only use this kind of thing if absolutely necessary. I don't even know whether it's a documented feature.

Comment: Please note that `Item.didDoIt` must be used as a whole. `.didDoIt` alone won't do because `(Element) -> (T) -> ()` has no member `didDoIt`, and `\.didDoIt` also won't do because it's not a key path.